# When HAVING is used with GROUP BY, does SQL only do aggregation?

Tags: mysql

In the following statement:

```
SELECT CustomerID, Country
FROM Customers
GROUP BY Country
HAVING count(CustomerID)>7
```

I want to return all customer IDs for countries with more than 7 customer IDs. But it only returns 1 ID per country.

I need to do the following to get what I want:

```
SELECT CustomerID, Country
FROM Customers
WHERE Country in (SELECT Country FROM Customers GROUP BY Country HAVING COUNT(CustomerID)>7)
```

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Obviously this is not for **Sql Server** why is it tagged ?

Comment: `Mysql` allows this weird way of grouping.. I don't know on what basis `customerID` is chosen in result in first query

Comment: You are grouping on `country`. That means return 1 record for each distinct `country`. MySQL will then return 1 random `CustomerID` for each distinct `country` since you didn't specify how to aggregate `customerid`. Your second query is the right way to do this.

Comment: mysql or sql server? please remove tag which isn't relevant.

Comment: @Pரதீப் MySQL will grab the first `CustomerID` it encounters from storage for each distinct `country` which is dangerous and stupid. Thankfully in 5.7 or greater it will error with a bad query like this by default (just like every RDBMS).

Comment: @JNevill - Not sure where this could be useful in real world applications..

Comment: So what's the question? You have working code. And @Pரதீப் why couldn't this be for SQL Server? The syntax looks correct to me unless i've overlooked something

Comment: It's a syntax that is generally used when it's known by the developer that `customerid` is distinct for each `country`, so they just lazy-group-by on the one field. I've seen it in MythBackend source code. I can't imagine any good reason to allow it either though. It's always really bugged me.

Comment: @scsimon The first query wouldn't even run on SQL Server since `customerid` isn't included in an aggregate formula nor is it present in the `GROUP BY` clause. Every RDBMS but MySQL would error out. I presume the confusion by OP is related to the oddball behavior of MySQL for even allowing the first query to run.

Comment: @scsimon - If you look closely there is non aggregate column(`CustomerID`)  present in `select` which is not part of `group by` and the query works for OP.. So it is not Sql Server

Comment: @Pரதீப் In strict mode for MySQL the query would fail because you cannot select a column that you aren't grouping by

Comment: @JNevill - So true.. even it bugs me..  whenever I see queries like this in SO I always say Mysql allow this weird grouping

Comment: @HunterMcMillen - What I feel is this shouldn't be allowed in any mode.. It doesn't make any sense in real world

Comment: Ah I see now that they said it actually returns values just the incorrect one @Pரதீப்  good catch

Comment: Good catch @JNevill

Answer (score 0):

You can structure this nicely as a join to a subquery:

```
SELECT CustomerID 
FROM Customers c
JOIN (
  SELECT Country 
  FROM Customers 
  GROUP BY Country 
  HAVING COUNT(CustomerID) > 7
) c2 on c.Country = c2.Country;
```